# Keyboard frequency in Linux

Tags: c, linux, keyboard

I am trying to read from keyboard event device (`/dev/input/event5`) with `read` in non-blocking mode. `read` returns -1 if nothing to read. Question is how often I should check event device for new input (how long program should sleep before next read attempt)? If I push the button and don't release how often driver sends this event to event device?

*UPDATE:*
My program sends keycodes read from event device through network (I write low-level KVM). So I have socket timeout in this case and want to know appropriate value for this timeout. I want that keycodes sent in real-time without delays.

Comment: If `read` returns -1 then an error has occurred (it should return 0 if there is no data in non-blocking mode).

Comment: @Demindiro: `EAGAIN`/`EWOULDBLOCK` is the "error". Nonblocking reads do **not** return 0 when there's no data. 0 is only legal for `read` to return to indicate end-of-file condition.

Comment: @R.. You're right, my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, when you want to read from a non-blocking file descriptor, it's best to wait on it using a function like `select(2)` or `poll(2)` (or using the `epoll` family of functions).  These functions let you sleep a certain amount of time (or forever) and be woken up when there's new input to process.

The driver may send data to the device file as each scancode is read or it may batch related requests at its option, so you shouldn't rely on a particular timeout.  Instead, specify an appropriate timeout to `select(2)` or `poll(2)` depending on how long you want to wait if nothing comes in.  If something comes in, you will be woken up earlier and `read(2)` should then succeed (although you should be prepared to be woken up spuriously; that is, when there is nothing to read).

If you don't know which function to use and are not using a large number of file descriptors, `select` is probably the easiest choice.  The manual page provides an example of how to use it.

Comment: My program sends keycodes read from event device through network. So I have sockets timeout in this case and I want to know appropriate value for this timeout.

Comment: You can use `select` for both your network socket and your event device and be notified whenever the event device is ready for reading or the socket is ready for writing.  You don't need to know the kernel's timeout.  In any event, it can vary across versions or compile flags, so any value we gave you would be wrong in some cases.